# Passing a file path from XSL to JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, xslt

I am trying to pass a folder path from XSL to JavaScript. Function is there in JavaScript and that function is getting called on onClick button of a HTML button in XSL. The path is like "C:\ABC\DEF\GH". While putting an alert I saw that path is getting sent like: "CABCDEFGH". All the slashes are removed. Even I removed the function call on OnClick event and just put an alert there with hard coded path, still same thing. It removed all the slashes.

```
<img class="viewcls" src="images/copy.jpg" title="Copy Profile" onclick="fnCopyProfile({$CurlDPID},'{@T}','{SOURCE/I/@DP}')"/>
```

Here last parameter in fnCopyProfile function's last parameter is an XPath whose value will be a file path like C:\ABC\DEF\GH. In JS its coming without slashes.

Even if I put alert in XSL itself like:

```
<img class="viewcls" src="images/copy.jpg" title="Copy Profile" onclick="alert('{SOURCE/I/@DP}');fnCopyProfile({$CurlDPID},'{@T}','{SOURCE/I/@DP}')"/>
```

then also it is showing path without slashes.

However if I am doing this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="SOURCE/I/@DP" />
```

then it is showing path with slashes, but like this we can't pass value into JS, I guess.

How to send the exact path with slashes to JavaScript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: <img class="viewcls" src="images/copy.jpg" title="Copy Profile" onclick="fnCopyProfile({$CurlDPID},'{@T}','{SOURCE/I/@DP}')"/>

Comment: I meant by **editing** your question

Comment: Here in fnCopyProfile function last parameter(SOURCE/I/@DP) is an XPath that contains file path like I mentioned. When this is getting passed to javascript slashes are removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are escaping all `\` characters.  When used in a JavaScript string, `\` is used to denote a control character (e.g. `\n` for a newline).

So what you need to do is replace all `\` characters with `\\`.

I do not know how you would do that with the inline variables you're using (hopefully Dimitre will show us).

<strike>However, you *could* do it like this...</strike>

```
<img class="viewcls" src="images/copy.jpg" title="Copy Profile">
  <xsl:attribute name="onclick">fnCopyProfile(<xsl:value-of select="$CurlDPID"/>,'<xsl:value-of select="@T"/>','<xsl:value-of select="translate(SOURCE/I/@DP,'\','\\')"/>');</xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

**UPDATE**

The above cannot work, as `translate` works by replacing a single character with a single character.

If you are using XSLT 2.0, then I believe you can do this ([w3.org reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace))...

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(SOURCE/I/@DP,'\\','\\\\'")/>
```

The reason for the `\\` is that the 2nd and 3rd parameters are regular expressions, so need the `\` escaping.

If you are using XSLT 1.0, then I have just found [this post via Google](http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx) which provides a "search and replace" template

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
  <xsl:param name="text" />
  <xsl:param name="replace" />
  <xsl:param name="by" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
      <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text"
        select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Which you should be able to call like this (I have put it into a variable to make it clearer)...

```
<xsl:variable name="mypath">
  <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="SOURCE/I/@DP"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="replace">\</xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="by">\\</xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<img class="viewcls" src="images/copy.jpg" title="Copy Profile">
  <xsl:attribute name="onclick">fnCopyProfile(<xsl:value-of select="$CurlDPID"/>,'<xsl:value-of select="@T"/>','<xsl:value-of select="$mypath"/>');</xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

Comment: Its saying transform() in unknown XSLT function

Comment: Sorry @Akki, I realised I'd gotten it wrong and updated my answer to `translate` (you should see the note I put at the bottom)

Comment: Still same thing. It removed all the slashes.

Comment: Try doing this (not within the `<img>` but somewhere else in the HTML) and see what comes out... `<pre><xsl:value-of select="SOURCE/I/@DP"/></pre><br/><pre><xsl:value-of select="translate(SOURCE/I/@DP,'\','\\')"/></pre>`

Comment: In both cases it is writing path with single slash.

Comment: @Akki, damn, no of course, it's never going to work... going to think about it, and I'll get back to you

Comment: @Akki - are you using xslt 1.0 or xslt 2.0?

Comment: xslt 1.0. Will that matter at all?

Comment: This method of replacing using template worked. Thanks a million for the help.

Comment: You're welcome @Akki, well done for getting it sorted :-)  Good luck with the rest of your project.